# How to pass two scope in one ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass recipe and ingredients scope through the ng-click function createRecipe(). I declared the ingredients as array.

```
$scope.ingredients = [];
$scope.recipe = {};
```

then in my html, I have inputs that have $index

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="RecipeName" name="RecipeName" required ng-model="recipe.Name">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="IngredientQuantity" name="IngredientQuantity" ng-model="ingredients.Quantity[$index+1]" />
```

then when user clicks submit I need to get both scopes

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createRecipe(recipe;ingredients)"/>
```

I will be referencing the recipeid in my ingredients table so I need them in one funtion.

```
$scope.createRecipe = function (recipe) {
    $scope.uploader.uploadAll();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Recipes/CreateRecipe',
        data: $scope.recipe
    }).then(function (response) {
        var recipeID = response.data;
        var vmRecipeIng = {
            Quantity: $scope.ingredients.Quantity,
            UOM: $scope.ingredients.UOM,
            Name: $scope.ingredients.Name,
            RecipeId: recipeID
        };
        vmRecipeIngs = vmRecipeIng;
        alert(vmRecipeIng);
        console.log(vmRecipeIng);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/RecipeIngredients/CreateRecipeIngredient',
            data: vmRecipeIng
        }).then(function (response) {
        }, function () { alert('Error CreateRecipeIngredient'); });
    }, function () { alert('Error CreateRecipe'); });
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass them in at all? `createRecipe()`, `recipe` and `ingredients` are all part of the same `$scope`. Just use the variables in the function. In your example code you are accessing `$scope.recipe` and not the passed in `recipe` so you are already ignoring the incoming variable.

Comment: @Intervalia I tried but it return as null or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs to have two parameters since your HTML passes two,

```
$scope.createRecipe = function (recipe,ingredient) {
}
```

also the function should have parameters separated by **`,`** not **`;`**

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createRecipe(recipe,ingredients)">
```

Comment: it still returns as `{Quantity: {…}, UOM: {…}, Name: undefined, RecipeId: 90}` in the console and Object object in the alert

Comment: Use Jon.stringify in the alert